# Iteratively take mean of column in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, filtering, vectorization

Hi I have a column of values in Matlab (PDS(:,39)).  This column is filtered for various things and there are two seperate flagging columns (PDS(:,[41 81])) that are either 0 for a valid row or -1 for a non-valid row.  I am taking the mean of the valid data, and if the mean is above 0, I'd like to make this value non-valid and take the mean again until the mean is below a certain value (0.2 in this instance).  Here is my code:

```
% identify the VALID values
U1 = (PDS(:,81)==0);
F1 = (PDS(:,41)==0);

% only calculate using the valid elements
shearave = mean(PDS(U1&F1,39));

while shearave > 0.2
    clear im
    % determine the largest shear value overall for filtered and
    % non-flagged
    [c im] = max(PDS(U1&F1,39));
    % make this value a NaN
    PDS(im,39)=NaN;
    % filter using a specific column and the overall column
    PDS(im,41)=-1;
    F1 = (PDS(:,41)==0);
    % calculate shear ave again using new flagging column - remove the ";" so I can see        the average change
    shearave = mean(PDS(U1&F1,39))
end
```

The output that Matlab gives me is:

shearave =

0.3032

shearave =

0.3032

shearave =

0.3032

etc

The loop is not re-evalulating with the new valid data.  How do I solve this problem?  Do I have to use a break or continue?  Or perhaps a different type of loop?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop, I'd do the following:

sort your data:

```
m=PDS(U1&F1,39);
[x isort]=sort(m);
```

Then calculate the cumulative mean of the sorted vector:

```
y = cumsum(x)./[1:numel(x)]';
```

Then truncate at 0.2, and retrieve the values needed using the indices found ...

```
ind=find(y<=0.2);
values_needed=m(isort(ind));
```

Comment: Yes, I just came to the same conclusion!  Sorted it descending and removed the values until the mean was below 0.2, identifying the ones I had to remove by their timestamp.  I had a loop in mine though - this will help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You iteratively replace values in column 39 with `NaN`. However, `mean` will not ignore `NaN`, but instead return `NaN` as the new average. You can see this with a little experiment:

```
>> mean([3, 4, 2, NaN, 4, 1])
ans = NaN
```

Therefore, `shearave < 0.2` will never be `true`.